# Watch.JS : callback is not getting called when I set variable dynamically. But works fine for array push

Tags: javascript

I am using [watchJS](https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS)  to set things dynamically on my view. Dynamically pushing into an array is working fine but the assignment is not working.

**UPDATE**

I just updated the snippet. In that you can see there is another object I am watching with the noMore option set to true. When I unset, it works fine. But I need to set it to true to avoid infinite calls.

```js
   var obj = {
  a :'a',
         b :'b'
    }

    watch(obj, function (a,b,c) {
  WatchJS.noMore = true;
         console.log("change in other ....",c);
    });
    obj.b = 'new'

    var newObj = {
        a: "a",
        b: "1",
        c: []
    }

    watch(newObj, "b", function (prop, ac, New, old) {
       console.log(" B set to ", New);
    }, 1,true)

    watch(newObj, "c", function (prop, ac,New, old) {
   console.log("C set to ", New);
    },1,true)
   
    newObj.b = "[inline] b" // this works
    newObj.c.push("[inline] c"); // this works

    setTimeout(function () {
     console.log('time')
        newObj.c.push("[timeout] c"); // this works
        newObj.b = "-[timeout ] b" // not working
    },5000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/melanke-watchjs@1.5.0/src/watch.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The console shows `B set to  [timeout ] c` . Is that not what you expect?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's showing `B set to [timeout] c` already. what is problem than ?

Comment: Yeah I can see it is working here. But it is not working on my project.  see this screenshot : https://i.imgur.com/sueIDOK.png

Comment: @NIKHILCM — We can't tell why it isn't working in the code you haven't shown us. It works in the code you have shown us!

Comment: can you check this video snippet if possible? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LKq0UdPbTgfb3E-h3n9aAdIvvusR0HF4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Quentin Updated the code,  can you just have a look ?

Comment: If you remove `WatchJS.noMore = true;`, it works. So it's somehow related to that option. What is the purpose of that option? In case you don't know, why are you using it? If the change should still be recorded, even with that option set, it may be a bug in the library.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `noMore`, once it's set to `true` it will never reset back to `false`. The array works because it uses a different watcher that does not check `noMore`.

Instead use `WatchJS.suspend(obj, prop)`. `suspend` will prevent the next watcher from being called.

```js
const obj = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
}

const newObj = {
    a: "a",
    b: "1",
    c: []
}

watch(obj, function (a, b, c) {
    console.log("Watch obj - newObj.b suspended!")
    // Next assign newObj.b call will not fire
    WatchJS.suspend(newObj, 'b')
});

watch(newObj, "b", function (prop, ac, newVal, old) {
    console.log("Watch newObj.b", newVal)
}, 1, true)

console.log('Assigning obj.b', obj.b = 'new')
console.log('Assigning newObj.b', newObj.b = "[inline] b")

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('timer 1')
    console.log('Assigning newObj.b, will not fire watch', newObj.b = "-[timeout ] b")
}, 500)

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('timer 2')
    console.log('Assigning newObj.b', newObj.b = "-[timeout ] b2")
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/melanke-watchjs@1.5.0/src/watch.min.js"></script>
```